# Order of eigenvalue and dimension of eigenspace in infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

how can we define the order of an eigenvalue of an operator A in infinite dimension and what's the relation between the order and the dimension of the eigenspace and the generalised eigenspace.

Comment: How do **you** define *order* of eigenvalue in finite dimension?

Comment: it's the number of times it appears in the characteristic equation

Comment: Thank you. So you mean the algebraic multiplicity, I think.

Comment: the algebric multiplicity is the  dimension  of the eigenspace?

Comment: No. It is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as root of the characteristic polynomial (in finite dimension). The *geometric* multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace in this case.